# Trying to learn Next JS, confused on how to remove /pages from my route but still keep a pages folder for clarity?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am learning next js and typescript at the same time, When making a test page just to say 'Hello from About' I put the about folder in my pages folder and put my page.tsx in that. but I can only load that route when I put /pages/about in the nav bar. Is there a way to remove the pages folder from directory so that i only need to put /about for the about page to show up but still keep it in the pages folder?

I know this a really beginner question but wanting to fully grasp next as i've heard so many good things about it while learning react

My folder structure is this

```
src - 
   pages - 
        about - 
        page.tsx

   page.tsx
```

so with the built in routing how i understand it,it automatically creates routes that way but the sad thing is with keeping it like this I have to put `/pages/about` to show my about page

Comment: why do you have `page.tsx` at outer most directory ?

Comment: Maybe `basePath` is what you are looking for ? In your `next.config.js` file, check for `basePath` variable and set it to `""` ( empty string ) if not already. It should be inside of the `module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({})` part.